# Como mejorar mi drag and drop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
   def Pixel_Distance(x1, y1, x2, y2): 
        global a, b, c
        if (x2 == x1) and (y2 == y1):
            pass
        else:
            a = y2 - y1
            b = x2 - x1
            c = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
           # print(c)

estado_clic = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)

c = 0     
while 1:
    estado_actual = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    if estado_actual != estado_clic:  # si cambia de estado
        estado_clic = estado_actual
        if estado_actual < 0:
            x,y = pyautogui.position()
            while 1:
                x1, y2 = pyautogui.position()
                Pixel_Distance(x,y, x1,y2)
                if c > 23:
                    c = 0
                    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0,0,0)
                    break
```

el código que les muestro arriba, funciona bien, al hacer click y mover el mouse 23 pixeles a cualquier dirección ejecuta `win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0,0,0)` pero quiero mejorarlo aun mas.

tengo dos ideas una es con el código de arriba modificando `if c > 3:` mover el mouse 3 pixeles en cualquier dirección y terminar de añadir los otros 23 pixeles en la linea en la que va dirigida el mouse(aleatoria), como puedo lograr esto?

la otra idea es: lograr con esta funcion `pyautogui.drag(0, 0, 0, button='left')` sepa a donde quiero dirigirme al momento de mover el mouse y terminar de completar los pixeles restantes sea diagonal izquierda, diagonal derecha o hacia arriba, abajo, derecha, izquierda. algo así:

```
while 1:
    estado_actual = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    if estado_actual != estado_clic:  
        estado_clic = estado_actual
        if estado_actual < 0:
            x,y = pyautogui.position()
            while 1:
                x1, y2 = pyautogui.position()
                Pixel_Distance(x,y, x1,y2)
                if c > 5:
                    pyautogui.drag(c+25, 0, 0, button='left')
                    c=0
                    break
```

este código al momento de mover el mouse 5 pixeles en cualquier dirección, lo completa hacia la derecha, como puedo jugar con las matemáticas y hacer que funcione como espero? ya que al problema al que me enfrento es que no se vuelve funcional porque solo va hacia la derecha `c+30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te entiendo bien quieres prolongar la recta cierta distancia "d" después de haber presionado en dos puntos ¿verdad?. Puedes usar la fórmula de la recta "pendiente, punto".

Primero halla la pendiente de los dos puntos:  m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1).

La ecuación pendiente "m" punto (x1,y1) será:

```
y-y2= m(x-x2)     # ecuación 1
```

Ademas por el Teorema de Pitágoras(incluyes la distancia):

```
d**2= (y-y2)**2 +(x-x2)**2     # ecuación 2
```

Listo, tienes dos ecuaciones con dos incógnitas... tienes que despejar "x" y "y". El punto (x,y) son las coordenadas a una distancia "d" del punto (x2,y2).[image: Coordenadas de un punto (x,y) a una distancia d, dados los puntos (x1,y1) y (x2,y2)].

Despejando las variables y en Python sería:

```
# Dados los puntos (x1, y1) y (x2,y2) hallar el punto a una distancia "d" del punto (x2,y2)
#Sol. Debido a que la distancia en esa recta puede ser en ambas direcciones, hay dos soluciones.
if(x1 == x2): #evitar la división entre 0 de x1,x2
    x = x1
    if(y2>y1):
        y = y2+d
    else:
        y = y1+d
else:
    m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    if((x1>x2) & (y1>=y2)):
        x = x2-(d**2/(1+m**2))**(1/2)
        y = m*(x-x2)+ y2
        # print("Solución 1:("+str(x)+","+str(y)+")")
    elif((x1<x2) & (y1<=y2)):
        x = x2+(d**2/(1+m**2))**(1/2)
        y = m*(x-x2)+ y2
        # print("Solución 2:("+str(x)+","+str(y)+")")
print("Respuesta:("+str(x)+","+str(y)+")")
```

Referencia:
[https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendiente_(matemáticas)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendiente_(matem%C3%A1ticas))

Comment: gracias amigo, ya lo estoy probando, espero lograr lo que quiero! saludos y gracias nuevamente!

Comment: amigo, ya pude hacer que el código supiera a que dirección va, el problema que tengo ahora es que no logro calcular el recorrido que tendrá una vez que sepa a que dirección se dirija(ya que como es aleatorio no puedo especificar un x, y para calcularlo), me podrías orientar de nuevo y disculpa el abuso

Comment: Amigo, exacto, creo que no me expliqué bien. Usando esas dos ecuaciones puedes despejar la "x" y "y"  para hallar el punto que está a una distancia "d" del punto (x2, y2).  
Voy a editarlo para que se entienda mejor, no hice el despeje porque dará una expresión muy larga. Avísame si todavía no se entiende sí. Saludos!

Comment: De la ecuación 1 despeja la variable "y" y reemplaza en la ecuación 2, así hallarás el valor de "x", con ese valor puedes hallar "y". Ese punto que hallarás "(x,y)" es el punto que está a cierta distancia "d" del punto (x2,y2).

Comment: cree una funcion pendiente, y un if m < -0.48: cuando sea True completaria los pixeles restantes, aqui es donde me falla, si no es mucha molestia me puedes dar un ejemplo? o si no puedes me podrías recomendar algun video o algun post, muchas gracias por responder!

Comment: Si la pendiente es negativa significa que la recta está en descenso (es como cuando bajas de una colina), gráfica la recta de los puntos  (10,0) y  ( 0,10) ... esa recta tiene una pendiente negativa.. sólo tienes que reemplazarla ese resultado con los signo incluido en la ecuación.   NOTA: Un ejemplo de pendiente positiva es la recta de los puntos (0,0) y (10,10)  (es como subiendo una colina, asciende)

Comment: Un ejemplo sencillo sería el siguiente, tengo los puntos (0,0)  y (2, 2)  su pendiente será m = 1.  Ahora quiero hallar el punto que esté en esa recta a una distancia d = 4.243 (es la raíz cuadrada de 18, para que nos de números exactos) del punto (2,2), entonces mi ecuación 1 y 2 resultarán:  
> y – 2 = (1) (x-2);
>3**2 = (y-2)**2 + (x-2)**2;
Despejando de la ecuación 1 la variable “y”, y reemplazando en la 2, encontrarás x = 5, lo mismo para encontrar “y=5”. El punto (5,5) es la respuesta... está a una distancia d=4.243 del punto (2,2).

Comment: Si la pendiente es negativa, también funcionan estas ecuaciones, sólo reemplaza con el signo. Mira también este enlace: http://www.profesorenlinea.cl/geometria/Recta_Ecuacion_de.html
las dos ecuaciones son: "Ecuación pendiente punto" y "Teorema de Pitágoras". Con esas dos ecuaciones encontramos los puntos). Espero que se entienda, escríbeme si aún tienes problemas sí)

Comment: amigo, como puedo despejar x e y de las ecuaciones? para poder crear las funcionas, saludos bro!

Comment: @Kiyosaki vale, ya puse las formulas. No te olvides, que la distancia es a partir del segundo punto (x2,y2). Al despejar se obtiene dos soluciones (es lógico, por que la distancia puede ser a ambos lados del segundo punto, arriba o abajo, así que comparé para ver cual punto tomar en cuenta). puse en comentario ambas soluciones, pero la que imprime es la que estás buscando)))